# Expected values of dependent Gaussian variables

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

Let $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ be a set of three zero-mean Gaussian random variables with a covariance matrix of

$$
C=\sigma^2
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \rho & \rho
\\
\rho & 1 & \rho
\\
\rho & \rho & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
How can I find the following expected values

$E[X_1\mid X_2=x_2,X_3=x_3],\,E[X_1X_2\mid X_3=x_3]$ and $E[X_1X_2X_3]$?

This is a probloem of my homework, I have only a not-so-good way to deal with it.

Take the first question for example,I try to find the conditional PDF of
$f_{X_1|X_2,X_3(x_1|x_2,x_3)} $, and then directly get the answer by finding the means, but it seems to complex...

Comment: Maybe have a look at the "Conditional probability" section [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good thing about (zero-mean) multivariate normal distribution is that its structure is compatible with the inner-product structure arising from its covariance structure:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ccc}
\text{zero-mean gaussian distribution} & & \text{inner product space} \\
\hline
\text{covaraince} & \leftrightarrow & \text{inner product} \\
\text{independence} & \leftrightarrow & \text{orthogonality} \\
\text{conditioning} & \leftrightarrow & \text{orthogonal projection}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

For example, it turns out that

$$ \mathbf{E}[X_1 \,|\, X_2, X_3] = \alpha_2 X_2 + \alpha_3 X_3 $$

for some constants $\alpha_2, \alpha_3$, as if the 'vector' $X_1$ is projected onto the liner span of $X_2$ and $X_3$, and all you have to do is to determine them so that $Y = \alpha_2 X_2 + \alpha_3 X_3$ solves

$$\operatorname{Cov}(X_1 - Y, X_2) = \operatorname{Cov}(X_1 - Y, X_3) = 0, \tag{*}$$

i.e., $X_1 - Y$ is 'orthogonal' to the span of $X_2$ and $X_3$. In random variable's side, once $\alpha_2, \alpha_3$ satisfy the above relation, then $X_1 - Y$ is uncorrelated to $(X_2, X_3)$, which then implies that they are independent thanks to joint normality. So we indeed have

$$\mathbf{E}[X_1 \,|\, X_2, X_3]
= \mathbf{E}[(X_1 - Y) + Y \,|\, X_2, X_3]
= \mathbf{E}[X_1 - Y] + Y = Y. $$

Going back to solving $\text{(*)}$, this can be done in a systematical way, and yields the formula in @Gabriel's link. Anyway, the above equation reduces to

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \rho \\ \rho \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \rho \\ \rho & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \alpha_2 \\ \alpha_3 \end{bmatrix}
\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad
\begin{bmatrix} \alpha_2 \\ \alpha_3 \end{bmatrix}
= \frac{1}{1+\rho} \begin{bmatrix} \rho \\ \rho \end{bmatrix} $$

and so,

$$ \mathbf{E}[X_1 \,|\, X_2, X_3] = \frac{\rho}{1+\rho} X_2 + \frac{\rho}{1+\rho} X_3 $$

For the second part, similar idea shows that $X_i - \rho X_3$ and $X_3$ are independent for each $i = 1, 2$, and so,

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[X_1 X_2 \,|\, X_3]
&= \mathbf{E}[((X_1 - \rho X_3) + \rho X_3)((X_2 - \rho X_3) + \rho X_3) \,|\, X_3] \\
&= \mathbf{E}[(X_1 - \rho X_3)(X_2 - \rho X_3)] + \rho^2 X_3^2 \\
&= \sigma^2 \rho(1 - \rho) + \rho^2 X_3^2
\end{align*}

For the final problem, we may utilize the above result to compute

$$ \mathbf{E}[X_1 X_2 X_3]
= \mathbf{E}[\mathbf{E}[X_1 X_2 \,|\, X_3] X_3]
= \mathbf{E}[(\sigma^2 \rho(1 - \rho) + \rho^2 X_3^2)X_3]
= 0, $$

although the same conclusion follows from a more basic observation that the expectation of any odd-degree monomial in $X_i$'s is zero by symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

Does this figure of the distribution help you?

For your first problem integrate along the red line.

[image]